# Is there a way to make a Popup from External link work on Xamarin IOS WKWebview?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

Hi Guys I am a Xamarin Developer working on this project which has some menu Items that redirect to External links and load them into WKWebview in IOS . The issue that am facing is that some of the links are redirecting to pages that display a Login popup before you can see any content on that page . The popup doesn't show up on the WebView. I have tried enabling JavaScript and JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically on  my Custom render  but still its not working Am not sure what am doing wrong . It works fine if I redirect to Safari but that is not recommended. Following links is the code in my custom render and how I use it in xaml.

[Custom Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw4Ti.png)

[Xaml usage [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QJIU.png)enter image description here

Code in Custom renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
```

namespace Project.iOS.CustomRenderers
{

```
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomWebView, WKWebView>, IWKUIDelegate, IWKNavigationDelegate, IWKScriptMessageHandler
{
    WKWebView wkWebView;
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null)
        {

            WKPreferences pref = new WKPreferences() { JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true, JavaScriptEnabled = true, };
            var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
            config.Preferences = pref;
            wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
            wkWebView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
            wkWebView.UIDelegate = new MyWKWebViewDelegate();
            SetNativeControl(wkWebView);
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.Url));
            Control.LoadRequest(request);
            var webView = e.NewElement;
            webView.EvaluateJavascript = async js =>
            {
                var reset = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            await Control.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(js);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                                    //
                                }
                    });
                await Task.Run(() => { reset.WaitOne(); });
                return null;
            };
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Did you miss the `[assembly: ExportRenderer(....))]` attribute ? And you could show your complete codes of CustomRenderer and the popup page .

Comment: Hi leo thanks for the reply .I have edited the post to include custom render . Yes Export render is there and seem to be working but the only that is not working are the pages with a Login popop.

Comment: If you don't use a popup page,use a normal contentpage to open the webview,could it work ?

Comment: Sorry Leo  the popup is from the external ull that am opening through the WebView so I have no control on it . So what happens a user clicks a menu Item which opens an external website Url through a webview .First thing to show on the page from the url  is a popup to login . Its not showing up.

Comment: If you  let your CustomWebViewRenderer extends WkWebViewRenderer,could it work ?Like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview#create-the-custom-renderer-on-ios).

Comment: Thanks Leo Will trry it out

Comment: If it still could not work,you could share a simple sample,then i will test it later.